# Checking a file's modification date

Tags: c

I'm checking whether a file has been modified or not in order to refresh the content...
However, I need a couple improvements :

- How do I test the return value of stat to tell if it failed ?
- The returned errno numbers may change between glibc versions, right? In this case it is useless to do `errno==`...  How do I fix that?

```
int is_refreshing_needed (char * path)
{
    int refresh_content;
    struct stat file;
    stat(path, &file);
//File does not exist or Permission Denied or the file has not been modified
    if( errno == 2 || errno == 13 || file.st_atime > file.st_mtime ) {  
        refresh_content=0;
    }
    else { 
        refresh_content=1;  
    }
    return refresh_content; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"man stat" is your friend.  This is from the 'return values" section of the man page:

"Upon successful completion, 0 is returned. Otherwise, -1  is returned and errno is set to indicate the error."

The return values include: 
EOI, EOVERFLOW, EACCESS, EFAULT
and there are others.  These errors are errors from the stat() system call and will *not* change with gcc/glibc version.

to access the error information, you need to include

`#include <errno.h>`

and you can use the perror() function to get the error text (you need to `#include <stdio.h>` for the perror() declaration).  see "man perror" for more information.

also, please don't use numbers like 2 (No such file or directory) and 13 (Permission denied).  please use the #define'ed names to make the code easier to read.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `stat(2)` on my system states:

```
RETURN VALUES
     Upon successful completion, the value 0 is returned; otherwise the
     value -1 is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the
     error.
```

You must check the return value of the call to `stat()` to determine whether the call succeeded or failed. So:

```
if (stat(path, &file) != 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of error value from [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat):

> **EACCES** Search permission is denied for
>   one of the directories in the path
>   prefix of path.
>
> **EBADF** filedes is bad.
>
> **EFAULT** Bad address.
>
> **ELOOP** Too many symbolic links
>   encountered while traversing the path.
>
> **ENAMETOOLONG** File name too long.
>
> **ENOENT** A component of the path path
>   does not exist, or the path is an
>   empty string.
>
> **ENOMEM** Out of memory (i.e. kernel
>   memory).
>
> **ENOTDIR** A component of the path is not
>   a directory.

Use this constants instead of number value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use constants (because they are defined in stat.h):

> The stat() function shall fail if:
>
> ```
>    EACCES Search permission is denied for a component of the path prefix.
>
>    EIO    An error occurred while reading from the file system.
>
>    ELOOP  A loop exists in symbolic links encountered during resolution of 
>           the path argument.
>
>    ENAMETOOLONG
>           The length of the path argument exceeds {PATH_MAX} or a pathname
>           component is longer than {NAME_MAX}.
>
>    ENOENT A component of path does not name an existing file or path is an 
>           empty string.
>
>    ENOTDIR
>           A component of the path prefix is not a directory.
>
>    EOVERFLOW
>           The file size in bytes or the number of blocks allocated to the file
>           or the  file serial number cannot be represented correctly in the 
>           structure pointed to by buf.
>
>    The stat() function may fail if:
>
>    ELOOP  More  than  {SYMLOOP_MAX}  symbolic  links were encountered during 
>           resolution of the path argument.
>
>    ENAMETOOLONG
>           As a result of encountering a symbolic link in resolution of the 
>           path argument, the length of the substituted pathname string 
>           exceeded {PATH_MAX}.
>
>    EOVERFLOW
>           A value to be stored would overflow one of the members of the stat 
>           structure.
> ```

from man -s3 stat

Answer (score 0):

When stat fails it's return -1 ;>

so

```
if (stat() == -1)
    // stat fail
else
    // can refresh if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to check the value of `errno` within your function: just check the return value of `stat()` and let the caller handle specific errors, eg

```
errno = 0;
is_refreshing_needed("foo");
if(errno) switch(errno)
{
    case ENOENT:
    puts("file not found");
    break;

    /* ... */

    default:
    puts("unexpected error condition");
}
```